# K Nearest Neighbor Cross Validation Output

Tags: java, r, weka, knn

My goal is to create a graph (histogram) of the chosen k-nearest neighbor (classification technique) Ks chosen through leave one out cross validation (I have 46 rows of data so there should be 46 different K's chosen, many of which will be the same, but some that may be different.)

I see two possibilities. First, RWeka's (package that lets you interface with Java-based Weka data mining tool) IBk. My questions (read for more info): 1) Do you think it's possible to get into the "black box" of the R-Java interface to pull out the data I want using Rweka's IBk function? 2) What does R's knn function output mean? 3) Where would I place the sink function in my leave one out approximation script to capture the results of each run through?

Here's what I've been trying:

```
t1 <- IBk(class~., data=mydata, control=Weka_control(K=10, X=TRUE))
t1
```

The X=TRUE has the algorithm run using leave one out cross validation and output the best classifier (K):

```
IB1 instance-based classifier using 5 nearest neighbour(s) for classification
```

According to the documentation as far as I can tell, X = TRUE is the only way for this algorithm to run cross validation. However, this results in a sort of black box and I'm unable to see the intermediate values I'm after. However, even if I could, I am having difficulty getting out any meaningful data in a non-copy and paste fashion as the output is a Java object so converting the above output to a string (toString) and then pulling the number out doesn't work. Without more Java knowledge (or really any at all) I feel like this is a loosing battle unless one of you are familiar with Java and have an idea.

My next choice was knn (in class library), trying to manually use leave one out cross validation using something like the following:

```
x=1
y=2
while (y<11) {
while (x<47) {
train <- mydata[1:46 !=x,]
test <- mydata[x,]
t1 <- knn(train, test, train$class, k=y, use.all=TRUE)
x=x+1 }
y=y+1}
```

I would sink each readout into a single file for later (not sure where to place that sink, so suggestions on that would also be appreciated). However, I'm not sure what to make of what I get out of the knn function (factor classifications of the test set). With my three classes, I get a readout of 0, 1, and 2s. How would I turn this information into the graph I'm imagining?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My head hurts reading this.

Comment: My head hurts trying to figure it out. Will try to reword though. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to work with? You're a lot more likely to get an answer with a reproducible question. Post some data and I'll try out the `caret` package, as it gives LOOCV results for each iteration.